# Is it possible to encrypt a file when adding it to an old zipped folder with 7zip?

Tags: encryption, zip, 7-zip, aes

So, I've been encrypting my online backups with AES 256 using 7zip. However, when I go to add a file to the old archive by opening it with 7zip and dragging the file I want to add into the 7zip window it is added,  but not encrypted. I've been extracting my files and re-compressing them whenever I want to change them or add to them, but I'm hoping there is a better way to do this (either by encrypting the files when I add them to the archive or configuring them once they are in).

To be clear when I'm adding a new file to an old archive the old files stay encrypted but the new ones are not encrypted, and I want the ones I add to be encrypted also.

Comment: "by opening it with 7zip and dragging the file I want to add into the 7zip window it is added" - By doing this, you are creating a new 7zip unecrypted archive (temporary os directory), which replaces the existing one (if you give it the same name).  If you want it encrypted, extract the contents to a direcotry, and create a new encrypted archive, from the a contents of that new directory.

Answer (score 1):

So, after a bit of experimentation I found a work around. If anybody here is having the same problem I was then this is how to fix it:

First extract your archives (a pain, but you'll only do this once). After re-compress your folder as an unencrypted zipped folder (or whatever type archive you choose). Once that is done select your new, unencrypted archive in 7zip and choose "Add to Archive". This time encrypt it (I recommend AES 256).

Once you've got your encrypted file you can delete your old, unencrypted file. Now open the new, encrypted file, right click on the archive in it, and choose "Open Outside". Enter the password, then edit your archive. Once you are done you should get a notification that the file was modified, click yes to save the changes, then you should get a second notification, choose yes again and you're done.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying here: Put an unencrypted zip file into an encrypted archive so the encryption thinks it's just a single file that gets updated

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-Click on file you want to add to open context menu
2. 7zip--> add to archive..
3. Select the archive you want to add your file to
4. Select Encryption, enter a password
5. Click Ok

I got this from a similar question from StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283750/7zip-add-encryption-to-files

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any GUI options for 7zFM.exe

However a password can added by command line which does not do what you wish.

- 7z a archive.7z -psecret -mhe \ {path} \wildcards
- 7z x archive.zip -psecret
- -psecret compresses *.txt files to archive.7z using password "secret".
- -mhe  encrypts archive headers ( switch), so filenames will be encrypted.

Comment: Thanks for the help, although I found a solution while experimenting that allows me to stay within the GUI.

Comment: then add your solution for others

Comment: I added it the same time I made the comment